# Calling API endpoint from frontend doesn't return data but calling API directly works

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I have a React component that I want to render as a table based on the data returned from my endpoint - below is how I fetch the data I want to render:

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const result = await axios("http://localhost:5000/projects", {
        withCredentials: true,
      });
      setProjects(result.data);
      console.log(result.data);
    })();
  }, []);
```

The `console.log(data)` does not display the data in the console. If I call the endpoint directly (using the same JWT cookie), I get a response. Below is the route used for the endpoint:

```
router
  .route("/")
  .all(requireAuth)
  .get((req, res) => {
    Project.find()
      .then((projects) => res.json(projects))
      .then(console.log("test"))
      .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
  });
```

Note that I call requireAuth:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const requireAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.jwt;
  console.log("test token:" + token);

  // check json web token exists & is verified
  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, decodedToken) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/home");
      } else {
        console.log(decodedToken);
        next();
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log("test");
    res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/home");
  }
};

module.exports = { requireAuth };
```

If I remove this middleware from the route, I can render the table in the frontend without any issues:

[image]

So why is it when calling it directly, it responds as expected (and when I remove the middleware), but doesnt return data to the frontend when the middleware is in use?

Comment: Could you check if it throws a CORS error in the console ?

Comment: Ah, yes, there is. "Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call and wait for one more async func to get to the data: json()